# Which microphone should I buy for filmmaking: RODE Videomicro, MOVO VXR 10 or ZOOM H1n?

Tags: microphone

I am thinking about an external mic or audio recorder. I watched tons of Youtube reviews but still have no clue which to buy. I was primarily thinking about the MOVO VXR 10 but some say that preamps on my G85 are too sensitive for this microphone. On the other hand, I was considering an all in one solution as ZOOM H1n.

Could you please help me to choose and give reasons for your choice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! You'll need to give us more information for an informed answer. What are you going to be producing? Who or what will be your subjects? What environments will you be shooting in?

Comment: I will be primarily recording vlogs, interviews, short-films and maybe podcasts someday. So I will be recording conversations mostly, maybe ambient sounds but thats not necessary. I’m looking for an all in one solution to solve these tasks